# When (and if) does the Winter Bash / Hats start this year?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

I have not seen anything about Winter Bash starting yet and Hanukkah has started as it is a bit early this year.  Are we doing hats this year?

Comment: https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: Bit disappointed it hasn't started yet, but Thanks!

Comment: I'm also sad that the Winter Bash won't start until after Hanukkah is over but I'm guessing the Winter Bash starts the same time each year.

Comment: The countdown ends at 2018-12-12 00:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318712/295232) by @Eran on Meta Stack Exchange:

> We have a [countdown](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/)!
>
> [image]
>
> It looks like Winterbash 2018 will begin on Wednesday Dec 12 '18!

Comment: I want a sweater of that!

Answer (score 1):

Its started!

You can visit now https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/

Keep Earning Hats!

Comment: Thanks for the hats up.